# using pmrpcm library for sound output from Teensy3.2

Tags: teensy, tmrpcm

I converted an MP3 sound effect (5 seconds long) to WAV to play it out of a Teensy3.2 with speaker connected to PWM output pin.  The TMRPCM library specifically talks about **Arduino AVR boards**, but doesn't mention Teensy.  On the PJRB (Teensy) website, the only info I can get is for their high quality audio shield with extensive programming.  I just want to play the simple WAV file from the SD card where it is located.  (I can display images on a GLCD from SD card, so not a problem).  The problem is when I compile my sketch I get many errors related ONLY to the the library.  If I don't include the TMRPCM library, there are no errors.  *I DON'T NEED high quality sound!*  Any ideas?  Another library perhaps, or tweaks to existing?  I can post the errors if necessary, they seem to be related to timers not being declared in the .h file.

Comment: Teensy 3.2 is not AVR Arduino. TMRPCM is *only* for AVR Arduino. Since the Teensy 3.2 has high quality sound why would someone port the low quality TMRPCM library to it? You *could*, but a simpler method is just to use a timer for sample rate and adjust PWM duty cycle per sample with a carrier frequency > 2x the maximum sample frequency.

Comment: Sometimes you don't need the expensive fountain pen...just a pencil.   The Teensy should do EVERYTHING and more than an AVR chip, in my opinion.  having said that, I'm using an el-cheapo ISD1820 sound module with small amplifier module and getting exactly the results I want.   I had been hoping to put a number of sound bytes on SD card, but this works and modules are so cheap I can use more than one.   Get 20 seconds of sound.

Comment: The Teensy *can* do everything the AVR Arduinos can, and more. It's just a SMOP. No one has needed it to do what you want, since it does better than what you want, so no one has bothered to program it yet.

Comment: I understand but I wanted to use TRMPCM to have a library of MP3/WAV SFX on an SD card.  Surely others would want such a thing, it would be great for games for example.  Another analogy: I wanted a small transistor radio, not a complete component stereo system.

Comment: So why use a Porsche to go shopping?